# Probleme bei der Interpretation eines Satzes

Tags: comparative, interpretation

ich bin [hier](https://www.tagesschau.de/wirtschaft/unternehmen/insolvenzen-105.html) auf den folgenden Satz gestoßen

> Einiges spricht dafür, dass mehr Unternehmen die Coronakrise überstehen als befürchtet

Mir ist klar, dass gemeint ist, dass man befürchtet hat, dass weniger Unternehmen die Corona-Krise überstehen, als nun möglicherweise eintreffen wird (was ja positiv wäre).

Aber ich lese den Satz so wie er da steht: dass man befürchtet hat, dass Unternehmen die Krise überstehen und dies nun - möglicherweise - übertroffen wird.
So, als ob es negativ wäre, die Krise zu überstehen (weil `als` komparativ Ungleichheit darstellt & `befürchten` die Erwartung auf etwas negatives darstellt).

Habe ich hier einen Denkfehler?

Comment: Dann habe ich den gleichen Denkfehler. Der Satz ist in der Tat etwas ungeschickt. Eine Stilblüte, könnte man sagen :-)

Comment: Das sehe ich auch so. Es klingt nach "Wir haben ja schon befürchtet, dass das eine oder andere Unternehmen die Krise übersteht, aber jetzt schaffen es womöglich sogar viele...."

Comment: Hier ist noch einer, der das so sieht. :-) Für mich ist es eine Stilblüte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das Problem ist das Wort "befürchtet", das eine negative Erwartung ausdrückt. *Mehr als befürchtet* bedeutet stets, dass eine solche negative Erwartung noch übertroffen wird.

Anders gesagt: Es wird befürchtet, dass etwas Negatives eintritt. Die Formulierung

> dass mehr davon eintritt als befürchtet

sagt ganz klar, dass die Situation noch schlimmer ist als befürchtet. Ein korrektes Beispiel ist

> Einiges spricht dafür, dass mehr Fälle von Long Covid auftreten als befürchtet.

Dass Unternehmen die Coronakrise überstehen ist aber keine Befürchtung, sondern eine positive Erwartung und die Kombination

> dass mehr Unternehmen die Coronakrise überstehen als befürchtet

konterkariert die Intention des Satzes. Richtigerweise konnte man befürchten, dass viele Unternehmen die Coronakrise **nicht** überstehen. Korrekt ist also die Formulierung

> Einiges spricht dafür, dass weniger Unternehmen die Coronakrise nicht überstehen als befürchtet.

Eine neutrale Formulierung ist

> Einiges spricht dafür, dass mehr Unternehmen die Coronakrise überstehen als erwartet.

Es wurde erwartet, dass viele Unternehmen die Coronakrise nicht überstehen - aber es spricht einiges dafür, dass diese Erwartung nicht zutrifft. Im letzten Satz kann man *erwartet* ohne Weiteres durch *befürchtet* ersetzen:

> Es wurde befürchtet, dass viele Unternehmen die Coronakrise nicht überstehen - aber es spricht einiges dafür, dass diese Befürchtung nicht zutrifft.

Answer (score 0):

Ich befürchte, dass das ein Beispiel für die nicht immer eindeutigen Bezüge ist, die wir in der deutschen Sprache als Nebenprodukt der großen Wahlfreiheit der Wortstellungen nun einmal in Kauf nehmen müssen. Der Satz lässt sich nämlich auch so umstellen:

> Einiges spricht dafür, dass Unternehmen die Coronakrise überstehen -- sogar mehr als befürchtet.

Wenn man das Partizip **befürchtet** in einen Satz auslagert, lässt sich aber auch diese Fassung umformen:

> Einiges spricht dafür, dass mehr Unternehmen die Coronakrise überstehen. Dass das passiert, befürchteten einige.

Ich fürchte, es gibt keine Regel, die einer der Deutungen der anderen vorzieht. So etwas lässt sich wohl nur durch "defensive Formulierung" und nicht durch Grammatik verhindern, so unbefriedigend das auch ist.

Comment: Aber ging es nicht konkret um die Formulierung aus der Frage? Wenn ich da Dinge heraus- oder durch Gedankenstriche abgrenze, dann ist das nur schwer vergleichbar, oder?